# Как сделать Canvas спидометр на VUE?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, canvas

Недавно взял заказ на игровой Hud, для одного проекта.
Проблема в том, что я раньше не сталкивался с Canvas, да и не до конца понимаю как его использовать во VUE **реактивно**.

Сам принцип работы: -- Спидометр должен считывать значения из стейта, а именно значения `state.speed` и `state.maxSpeed` и подставляться в данный Canvas.

Хотел бы попросить помощи у тех, кто разбирается лучше меня. Помощь в виде направления на чтение материала или же помощь кодом с объяснением действий. Всем кто не останется равнодушными и не пройдет мимо, спасибо.

> Figma: https://www.figma.com/file/d0I6yGnc90yFGxq4yQw1qS/...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Canvas предусматривает императивную отрисовку, а не декларативную. Получается, Vue (как библиотека для упрощения работы с DOM через предоставление декларативного сахара) к данному API не подходит никаким боком.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [пользовательскую директиву](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html), которая даст вам возможность делать низкоуровневые операции с DOM(отрисовку `canvas`).

Первым [аргументом](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%85%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) в директиве `v-draw` будет элемент, к которому привязана ваша директива - `canvasElement`, вторым `binding` - объект, в свойстве `value` которого будут данные(в примере `state`).

Привожу пример для наглядности данного подхода:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    state: {
      speed: 0,
      maxSpeed: 200,
    },
  },
  directives: {
    draw: function(canvasElement, binding) {
      const {
        speed,
        maxSpeed
      } = binding.value

      const r = 50
      const x = 100
      const y = 100
      const koof = speed / maxSpeed + 0.8

      var ctx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

      ctx.fillStyle = "green";
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(speed, x - 10, y);
      ctx.fillStyle = "silver";
      ctx.font = "15px Arial";
      ctx.fillText('км/ч', x - 10, y + 10);

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineWidth = 10;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "#dddddd50"
      ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0.8 * Math.PI, 1.8 * Math.PI, false)
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.moveTo(x, y)
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "green"
      ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0.8 * Math.PI, koof * Math.PI, false)
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  },

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <canvas width="150" height="150" v-draw="state"></canvas>
    <br>
    <input type="range" v-model="state.speed" :max="state.maxSpeed" step="1" />
    <span>< Акселератор </span>
  </div>
</body>
```